# ¿Qué tan común es el uso de «criollo» en Colombia e Hispanoamérica, y qué quiere decir?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, hispanoamérica, colombia, terminología

Encontré esto en el artículo de Wikipedia [*Criollo people*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criollo_people) sobre el termino «criollo»:

> In the Spanish-language countries, the use of this word to refer to a person of Spanish or European ancestry today is **obsolete, except in reference to the colonial period**. The word Criollo, however, is used usually in some countries but with **other very different meanings**.

En realidad yo he encontrado el uso de este termino en Colombia y pensaba que se refiere a los descendientes españoles o sea gente de piel clara.

Alguien me dijo una vez cuando hablé de la gente blanca en el país (como hablarían los angloparlantes) que el termino usado en Colombia es «criollo».

Otra vez leí en un libro de Jorge Franco:

> La familia de Emilio pertenece a la monarquía criolla, llena de taras y abolengos...

¿Entonces tiene un significado diferente a lo que pensaba? ¿O puede que sea políticamente incorrecto el uso de la palabra para referirse a la gente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Colombia criollo es todo aquello que es producto de la mezcla de las culturas y razas originarias de América e importadas de África y Europa.

Criollo es aquello que ya es propio y único de nuestra región. Es algo que no es ni de nuestros aborígenes ni de los europeos o africanos ya que solo la mezcla lo puede producir.

En inglés tienen la palabra [Creole](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/creole) que para mí es muy similar.

> Creole: a person of mixed European and black descent, especially in the Caribbean

El uso histórico de la palabra es tal como lo dice la respuesta de Gustavson

El uso actual y coloquial de la palabra es para describir una cosa muy nuestra, muy autóctona, muy colombiana. Uno de los usos más frecuentes es por ejemplo "comida criolla" entre las cuales está una "[bandeja paisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandeja_paisa)" y un "[ajiaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajiaco)"

Si vas por la calle y ves un perro y no puedes determinar qué raza es porque es claramente la mezcla de varias razas, a eso le decimos un perro criollo.

Aunque la definición oficial es que solo los hijos de españoles nacidos en América eran los criollos (blancos nacidos en américa), mientras que los hijos de blancos mezclados con negros o indios eran **mulatos** o **mestizos** respectivamente hoy en Colombia entendemos Criollo como "mezclado".

No es despectivo y aunque en la actualidad no es muy usado para describir personas los actuales habitantes de Colombia seríamos en su mayoría criollos (yo me consideraría criollo).

Respecto a su uso diría que en temas raciales y principalmente en esta época donde muchos son sensibles es necesario tener claro con quién se está hablando. Hay quienes nos sentimos orgullosos de tener sangre negra, indigena, blanca y quien sabe que otra en las venas, pero hay personas que no. Por ejemplo según entiendo las personas de Luisiana (EEUU) se sienten orgullosas de ser *Creole* pero en las islas del caribe es un insulto. Para mi criollo no es insulto pero igual habla de mis ancestros y mi origen por lo que para algunos puede llegar a ser un tema sensible.

Comment: Gracias @DGaleano. Entonces, ¿toda la gente del país sería criollos? Me interesa en particular el uso de termino cuando se aplica a personas.

Comment: @aris amplié un poco la respuesta. Si. Para mi todos somos criollos en el sentido de "mezclados". **Criollo, mulato, zambo, mestizo** originalmente describían la **primera generación de nacidos en América** por lo que luego de tantas generaciones no tienen su significado original. Puedes verlo en la tabla que está al final de esta página. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casta

Answer (score 3):

Al menos en Argentina, el término "criollo" como caracterización étnica o sociológica se usa exclusivamente en contextos históricos para hacer referencia a los descendientes de los españoles que se radicaron en América, en contraste con los españoles (llamados "realistas" por su apoyo a la Corona y su oposición a los gobiernos patrios).

En el ámbito lingüístico, a veces se oyen oraciones como:

- (Mejor) Decilo en criollo.
- Hablá en criollo.

para decirle a alguien que hable claro, sin rodeos ni protocolos, con palabras sencillas y sin términos en otro idioma.